# Recursively select elements in numpy array

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I have a text file containing latitude and temperature values for points around the globe. I would like to take the average of all the temperature points between a specified latitude interval (i.e. every degree, from the South to the North Pole). This is the code I have so far:

```
data_in = genfromtxt('temperatures.txt', usecols = (0,1)) 
lat = data_in[:,0]
temp = data_in[:,1]

in_1N = np.where((lat>=0) & (lat<=1)) # outputs an array of indexes for all latitudes between 0°-1° North
temp_1N = temp[in_1N] # outputs an array of temperature values between 0°-1° North
avg_1N = np.nanmean(temp_1N) # works out the average of temperatures between 0°-1° North

plt.scatter(1, avg_1N) # plots the average temperature against the latitude interval
plt.show()
```

How could I improve this code, so it can be implemented 180 times to cover the Earth between -90°S and 90°N?
Thanks

Comment: Thanks Unutbu. How would this work if I have a lot of NaN values in the temperature column? I get a blank graph with my data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [np.histogram](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) to put the latitudes into bins. Usually, `np.histogram` would merely count the number of latitudes in each bin. But if you weight the latitudes by the associated `temp` value, then instead of a count you get the sum of the temps. If you divide the sum of temps by the bin count, you get the average temp in each bin:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# N = 100
# lat = np.linspace(-90, 90, N)
# temp = 50*(1-np.cos(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, N)))
# temp[::5] = np.nan
# np.savetxt(filename, np.column_stack([lat, temp]))

lat, temp = np.genfromtxt('temperatures.txt', usecols = (0,1), unpack=True) 
valid = np.isfinite(temp)
lat = lat[valid]
temp = temp[valid]

grid = np.linspace(-90, 90, 40)

count, bin_edges = np.histogram(lat, bins=grid)
temp_sum, bin_edges = np.histogram(lat, bins=grid, weights=temp)
temp_avg = temp_sum / count

plt.plot(bin_edges[1:], temp_avg, 'o')
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Note that if you have scipy installed, then you could replace
the two calls to `np.histogram`:

```
count, bin_edges = np.histogram(lat, bins=grid)
temp_sum, bin_edges = np.histogram(lat, bins=grid, weights=temp)
```

with one call to [`stats.binned_statistic`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic.html):

```
import scipy.stats as stats
temp_avg, bin_edges, binnumber = stats.binned_statistic(
    x=lat, values=temp, statistic='mean', bins=grid)
```